# ZFC - How to prove this statement

Tags: logic, proof-writing, set-theory, axioms

> Let $N$ be a set for which
>   $$\forall a\left(a\in N\iff a=\{\}\lor\exists b\left(b\in N\land a=\left\{b\right\}\right)\right)$$
>   Prove that
>   $$\forall P\left(\left\{\right\}\in P\land
> \forall a\left(a\in N\implies\left(a\in P\implies\{a\}\in P\right)\right)\implies\forall a\left(a\in N\implies a\in P\right)\right)$$

I'm having troubles with this problem. The first thing I tried to do is to expand the definition of set $N$. It seems that there is exactly one set $N$ for which the first statement is true. The second statement should be true for all $P$ and $a$ (we need to prove it).

My first attempt was to replace $a\in N$ in the second statement with $a=\{\}\lor\exists \left(b\in N\land a=\left\{b\right\}\right)$. The part $\{\}\in P\implies\{\}\in N$ is true, according to the definition of $N$. Now, I'm not sure how to deal with $\forall a\left(a\in N\implies\left(a\in P\implies\{a\}\in P\right)\right)$. Becuase there is an implication after this statement, the first idea which came to my mind is to try contradiction approach. Suppose that $\forall a\left(a\in N\implies\left(a\in P\implies\{a\}\in P\right)\right)$ is not true. So, I need to prove that then exists some $a$ from $N$ which is not in $P$. But, how to do that? I ran out of ideas.

One thing I noticed is that both in the definition of $N$ and the second statement, which we need to prove, appear $\{b\}$ (and in the second $\{a\}$). I suppose the trick is to somehow apply this part of the definition of set $N$ (or a set $N$, if there may be multiple sets $N$) such that these two parts cancel out using some logical implications.

I'm looking for an axiom-level proof. I mean, applying logical and ZFC axioms to this statement until we obtain an equivalence where on the left side is the statement we need to prove and on the right side is something which is true by definition.

Simply, what would be the easiest way to prove this? Thank you in advance if you decide to help :)

Comment: You're going to need to use the axiom of regularity; the result is not true without it.

Comment: @EricWofsey. *The result is not true without it.* - did I anywhere mention that the axiom of regularity is rejected? No, I'm just wondering how exactly to apply that axiom.

Comment: Well, my point is that most arguments in set theory _don't_ use the axiom of regularity, and if you're just applying your general intuition about sets, you are likely to be overlooking the extra power the axiom of regularity gives you in this context.

Comment: What you want to prove is not a well formed formula. $\implies$ is not associative. What you should do is just spell it out instead of writing complicated symbolic expressions...

Comment: @tomasz. *"What you want to prove is not a well formed formula."* - Implication is not associative, I know, but I'm pretty sure the formula is correct and it should look exactly like this.

Comment: @Math_974: Okay, now I see. Still, it is no less a point in case. It is really hard to understand what you've written (well, compared to how complicated it actually is). Instead, you can say that "For every $P$ with $\emptyset\in P$, if the singleton of every element of $P\cap N$ is in $P$, then $P$ contains $N$".

Comment: @tomasz. You're correct. However, just notice that $P$ does not necessarily contain $N$, but instead $N$ is subset of $P$.

Comment: @Math_974: That is what "contains" means. It is sometimes (well, often) used to mean "is an element of", and in most places it is obvious from the context what it means, but when dealing with things like this, the distinction is important.

Comment: $N$ is not unique. Let $x_0=\phi$ and $x_{n+1}=\{x_n\}$ for $n\in \omega.$  If $k\leq  \omega$ then $A(k)=\{x_n:n<k\}$ satisfies the conditions on $ N. $   In fact the conditions on $N$ imply that $N=A(k)$ for some $k\leq \omega. $ (The Axiom of Foundation, a.k. a. Regularity, is needed to prove it.)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet. I'm not sure what do you mean. *"for $n\in\omega$"* - what is $\omega$ here? What are $k$ and $A$? Btw, why do you use addition and comparison operators, how are they defined? Can you please explain it a bit more (as I get you, you're claiming that there are multiple $N$ satisfying the definition? can you provide an example?)

Comment: Let $x_0=\phi.$ For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $x_n=\{x_{n-1}\}.$  For $m\in \Bbb N $  the condition is satisfied by $N(m)=\{x_j:0\leq j<m\}$ and the condition is also  satisfied by  $\cup \{N(m) :m\in \Bbb N\}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet. Sorry, I really don't understand what you're trying to say. *"For $m\in\mathbb N$ the condition is satisfied by [...]"* - which condition? What does your notation $N(m)$ mean, and, again, why do you use natural numbers? Keep in mind that $\mathbb{N}$ is not defined and also addition ($+$) and relation ($>$) is not defined. I asked you to give as an example another set $N_x\neq N$ which satisfies the given statement for $N$.

Comment: The condition in the first sentence of the Q

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: No, that doesn't work.  The conditions on $N$ require that if $b\in N$, then $\{b\}\in N$ as well, which $N(m)$ does not satisfy.

Comment: @EricWofsey . It says that if $\phi \ne a \in N$ then $ a=\{b\}$ with $b\in N.$  It does not say that $a\in N\implies \{a\}\in N.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: It is a biconditional, not just an implication.  So if there exists $b\in N$ such that $a=\{b\}$, then $a\in N$.

Comment: @EricWofsey. $a\in N(2 \;)\iff$ $\; (a=\phi \lor a=\{\phi\})\;\iff$ $\; (a=\phi \lor (a=\{\phi\}\land \phi \in N(2)))\;\iff$ $\; (a=\phi \lor \exists b\in N(2)\;(a=\{b\})\;).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Your last $\iff$ is wrong.  What if $b=\{\phi\}$ instead of $b=\phi$?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey . There is a missing bracket in  the first display-line of the Q. Is this the problem?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Ah, yes, there should be.  I now realize what you are saying is correct if you parenthesize it the other way (but it did not even occur to me that this might be intended, since it is a very unnatural way to state the condition in that case!).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet. Can you please explain what "bracket" are you talking about? I see only parentheses and braces in my question and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 5):

The key idea you're missing is to use the axiom of regularity in order to make a stronger assumption about $a$.  Specifically, suppose there does exist $a\in N$ such that $a\not\in P$.  Let $S=\{a:a\in N\wedge a\not\in P\}$ (this set exists by Separation from $N$).  By assumption, $S$ is nonempty, so by the axiom of regularity there exists some $a\in S$ such that for all $b\in S$, $b\not\in a$.  Now try applying your line of thinking to this particular special $a$.

(Incidentally, I would very strongly advise *against* trying to think about things like this in purely formal "axiom"-level terms.  First come up with an informal argument based on your intuitive understanding of how sets and logic work and what the axioms mean, and then go back and try to make it fully formal once you have the informal argument.)

Comment: Seems valid. As soon as I completely understand your solution, I'll accept your answer. BTW, as a side question, is there exactly one set $N$ with such properties?

Comment: @Math_974: Yes. $N$ has as elements all iterated singletons of $\emptyset$, and if there was anything else besides in it, that would violate regularity.

Comment: I still didn't understand your answer. But in meanwhile, please tell me what do you think about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEDtv.png)?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but can you please take another look at my previous comment and tell me is the thing DanielWainfleet noticed correct and your answer wrong, or is your answer correct and his comment wrong? Can you just spend a minute to explain what is happening here? Thanks.

Comment: @Math_974: His comments are wrong, but in any case are irrelevant to my answer.